# Domain name missing in image paperclip in to_json rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the model that uses paperclip like this

```
has_attached_file :image, styles:  { :medium => "50x50>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

def image_url
    image.url(:medium)
end
```

I need it Json, So in my controller,

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @celebrity.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])}      
end
```

And the result is

```
"image_url":"/system/celebrities/images/000/000/003/medium/Designed___developed_by_wd_ApS.png?1430926991"
```

but, I need to include the domain name, localhost:3000 ,
So what I have to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Create module:

```
module WithDomain
  def domain
    @domain
  end

  def domain=(val)
    @domain = val
  end

  def domain?
    @domain.present?
  end
end
```

Change you model accordingly:

```
class Celebtiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WithDomain

  # existing staff

  def image_url
    if domain?
      URI.join(domain, image.url(:medium)).to_s
     else
      image.url(:medium)
    end
  end
end
```

and in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    @celebrity.domain = request.base_url
    render json: @celebrity.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])
  }
end
```

Comment: I am getting this error **undefined method `domain='**

Comment: Have you included `WithDomain` into `Celebrity` class?

Comment: Give me `Celebrity.ancestors` output

Comment: [{"id":1,"name":"Emma Watson","gender":"Female","category_id":"1","created_at":"2015-09-04T07:51:50.000Z","updated_at":"2015-09-04T08:18:49.000Z","image_file_name":"123131.jpg","image_content_type":"image/jpeg","image_file_size":54366,"image_updated_at":"2015-09-04T08:18:38.000Z","votes_count":1,"image_url":"/system/celebrities/images/000/000/001/medium/123131.jpg?1441354718","category":{"category":"celebrities"}}]

Comment: No, I mean `puts Celebrity.ancestors` from `rails c`

Comment: @saravana I can't find WithDomain module in your class. In the first line, of `Celebtiry` class add `include WithDomain`

Comment: you need also to define `WithDomain` module

Comment: I have created the module in the name of CelebrityHelper

Comment: And what gives `Celebrity.public_methods`?

Comment: `CelebrityHelper` in `app/helpers` ?

Comment: [http://pastie.org/10402354] Seriously I didn't understand as I am new to rails, yep it is in helper

Comment: Ok. Do it as I wrote above. Create `WithDomain` module in `app/models` (code is above) and add line `include WithDomain` into your `Celebrity` class.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10402381 facing the same issue 'undefined method `domain=' for #<Celebrity::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x4a200f8>'

Comment: It's because you try to apply `domain=` to array of celebrities :) Add `celeb.domain = request.base_url` into your loop `@celebrity.each`. And it's better to renames `@celebrity` into `@celebrities` it was very confusing.

Comment: Yep, got it ;-) what u mentioned above is right, thanks a lot, stuck with this minor issue for couple of days

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: (with existing code)

You can use [asset_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url) from `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` module which will give you the absolute url of your image. Just `include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` this in your model so that `asset_url` becomes available inside your model.
So, your method inside the model would be:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

def image_url
   asset_url(image.url(:medium))
end
```

**This is the easiest solution for you with your current code.**

#### Solution 2: (inside the controller)

In your controller `request` is available, so you can do:

```
URI.join(request.url, @celebrity.image.url(:medium))
```

which will give you the absolute url of the `image`. This will be an `URI` object, which can be converted to a String with `.to_s` method.

Here is the [issue from paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584) from where this solution is derived. Hope this helps.

Comment: `asset_url` is for `an asset in the public directory`, as documentation states. I doubt it will be useful here. Have you tested it?